# using :hover with css to make a div fade in or out

Tags: html, css

I've got two divs, div 1, and underneath it is hidden div 2. When I hover over div 1, I want it to hide, and show div 2. Then, once I mouse off of the area (now div 2), div 1 is displayed again.

Here is the code:

```
<a href="javascript://" class="hoverable">
<div class="normal" style="background:#666;">Hover over me!</div>
<div class="hover" style="background:#888;">Now you see me!</div>
</a>
```

and here is the css:

```
<style>
.hoverable {
  cursor:default;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.hoverable .hover {
  display:none;
}
.hoverable:hover .normal {
  display:none;
}
.hoverable:hover .hover {
  display:block;
}
</style>
```

My only problem with this is that is is very quick, cut and dry, and not very "fancy". I'd like to add something simple like a fade effect.

I've gotten this working, without the fade effect, here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pBDGW/

If anyone knows how to make those two divs transition with a fade-out, please let me know!

Comment: Use css3 transitions/animations to animate the opacity

Comment: [Like this: demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pBDGW/6/)?

Comment: @DavidThomas: sort of, but the divs now have on under the other. Instead of having them one on top of the other, I need one behind the other, so it would occupy the same space once hovered on. Otherwise, the fade effect is spot on. I tried using a combination of what you did plus what Andy said, and got this: http://jsfiddle.net/pBDGW/8/ still didn't work. I think I'm really bad at this, lol.

Comment: @SarahGrace you just need `position:absolute` to get the elements on top of each other: http://jsfiddle.net/pBDGW/11/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS transition with opacity like this:

```
.hoverable {
  cursor:default;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.hoverable .hover {
  opacity:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.hoverable .hover,
.hoverable .normal{
    transition: opacity .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
}

.hoverable:hover .normal {
  opacity:0;
}

.hoverable:hover .hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

You can see the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pBDGW/12/

Some explanation:

The transition applied to both div are the main code that make them fade in & out. You can read more about it here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/

Since you want the first div to fade out, and the second div to fade in, there will be a moment when both div have to be visible partially, hence `position: absolute` and some positioning on the second div (to make it overlap with the first div).

You are wrapping an anchor (`<a>`) around both div, which is actually not encouraged, so I have to give it `display: block;` . A better approach (HTML-wise) is to wrap both div inside another div (still use the same class `hoverable`), and use 2 different anchors inside each div.

EDIT: this approach http://jsfiddle.net/pBDGW/14/ works too. Here you only fade out the first div, while the second div is always visible but is hidden under the first div when not hovering. It is shorter css, but I don't recommend this approach though because I sometimes have issues with getting the first div to go on top on different browsers.

Comment: worked like a charm, and the whole lot makes more sense thanks to that article. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery, it has functions fadeIn and fadeOut and also its easy to hide() and show() on events mouseOver and mouseLeave.
You can see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yayjF/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(".hover").hide();
$(".normal").mouseover(function(){
    $(".normal").fadeOut(0);
    $(".hover").fadeIn(1000);
});
$(".hover").mouseout(function(){
    $(".normal").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".hover").fadeOut(0);
});});
```

Comment: the software on the forums doesn't like jQuery (they argue) so I try to avoid using it where I can, but thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

You can use transitions:

**ADD THIS TO YOUR :HOVER**

```
-o-transition:.5s;
-ms-transition:.5s;
-moz-transition:.5s;
-webkit-transition:.5s;
transition:.5s;
```

This adds the effect of fade IN/OUT

Addition: this will only work if you have property set for :hover, for example if you want to change the color, or background or what ever..